# Postgres coalesce to empty JSONB array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, coalesce, jsonb

How can I `coalesce` a `null` column into an empty `JSONB` array? This doesn't work:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(coalesce(null_column, '{}'::jsonb))
FROM table
WHERE id = 13;

-- ERROR:  cannot extract elements from an object
```

Neither this:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(coalesce(null_column, '[]'::jsonb))
FROM table
WHERE id = 13;

-- ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar
```

Comment: It really depends on the exact definition of  `null_column`, the data allowed in it and your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`{}` is an object but `jsonb_array_elements` expects an array, so replace `{}` with `[]`

Make sure that both arguments return a jsonb array. For example, if your column is an integer, you can use `concat` to add the square brackets and `::jsonb` for the conversion

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(coalesce(concat('[',my_column,']')::jsonb,'[]'::jsonb))
```

Comment: This works nice but for some weird reason, I still get `cannot extract elements from a scalar` if I use my column name instead of `null`.

Comment: @norbertpy forgot to address that - you will have to convert the column value to an json array because both arguments in the coalesce must return a json array

Comment: My column is JSONB for sure, but seems like Postgres cannot tell it's null. Even this `SELECT (CASE WHEN col IS NULL THEN 'is-null' ELSE 'is-not-null' END) AS r
FROM t
WHERE id = 13;` returns `is-not-null`.

Comment: But that will be another question. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: @norbertpy are you sure col should be null as opposed to the string that represents null in json?

Answer (score 2):

Here is SQL code for accomplishing what you want:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(coalesce(null_column, '[{}]'::jsonb))
FROM table
WHERE id = 13;
```

Comment: for just an empty array I think it's more like, `'[]'::jsonb` but thanks, you got me there with your answer